# How can I separate data between view_item_list events?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am using the `view_item_list` E-commerce Event to send a list (array) of items which I want to report the view frequency. I am doing this in 3 different parts of my site, each time using a different `item_list_name`.

My item lists don't all share the same category of items so my report containing all `view_item_list` events and items are polluted with items from each other's lists. GA4 seems to assume that all items are always related to each other.

When I am reporting (using a Free-form report), GA4 doesn't give me the ability to filter on `item_list_name`.

Nor can I filter by `item_category` or anything else that would functionally achieve the same thing.

I'm at my wits end as to how to separate the data so I can produce separated reports.

edit: I tested adding an `items` list/array to a custom event and the `items` object was dropped from the event when I checked it in DebugView.

At the moment I'm exporting the data to CSV and filtering it in a spreadsheet which is a pretty unsatisfactory solution!

Answer (score 1):

I have worked out how to do this.

tldr; The answer involves creating an Event Segment and then filtering by `item_list_name`. Then in your report, add the new Segment to 'Segment Comparisons' section.

Long;
I am using a Free Form report. To create the new Segment, click the + button in Segments section (upper left). Then select 'Event Segment'. Add a new condition for `item_list_name` matching or containing the name of the list that you have been submitting events for. Name your new Segment appropriately.

If you are not submitting an `item_list_name` for the Event, then you will need to modify Event log, then wait 24hours for GA4 to start logging the event.

While setting up the matching condition there is a Summary box on the side. This should tell you whether the matching condition is filtering or not. Although it didn't immediately work for me, after a few minutes it begun to work.

Finally after returning to the Report, drop the new Segment into the Segment Comparisons part of the report and the dataset should be filtered.